# How to add an html control inside a div or create a new <a> control beside another <a> control

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have `<div>` in my document and I want to create a new `<a>` tag/control inside it when I click on a button. When I click the button again it will create another `<a>` tag/control beside it without any spaces in between and when I click on the other button it will remove a particular `<a>` tag/control.

In other words a I want to create my own tab and target IFRAME when one of the `<a>` tag/control is click. I want to create it in pure javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var myA=document.createElement("a");` would create an element, you can set it's text by `myA.innerHTML` and src with `myA.src="http://www.google.com"`

To add it to the page you can do:

```
document.getElmentById("mydiv").appendChild(myA);
```

to remove:

```
var As=document.getElmentById("mydiv").getElementsByTagName("a");
var a = As[As.length-1];
a.parentElement.removeChild(a);
```

Comment: @acdcjunior Thanks, I did get lazy though setting the anchor's text :-)

Comment: @HMR yeah, that's ok, minor detail :) to an anchor tag, the other way (`myA.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text'));`) can be really too verbose.